# Magento 2 - Translation dictionaries query regarding using html

Tags: magento2, html, translation-dictionaries

I need to figure out whether I use the html in Magento 2 translation dictionaries For example I have this translation dictionaries file in which there are many relevant messages

```
\vendor\magento\module-advanced-checkout\i18n\en_US.csv
```

For instance if I want to use some html like let say I want to bold some word in the predefined message. Can I use the html translation dictionaries file if yes then how I use it and if no then tell me the other way to do html related changes to translation dictionaries messages?

I already use some of the Html tags in translation dictionaries file but it's not working

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because *translation dictionary* is not intended for `Hypertext Markup formatting`. As *[translation dictionary](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#translate_terms)* is a comma separated value `(.csv)` file used only to localize Magento storefronts.
So there is no way to use it to for text element formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not as simple as you think. if that is the case then how do anchor tag use in this translation file like `<a href=""%1"">click here</a>` ? check magento 2 core file `\vendor\magento\module-advanced-checkout\i18n\en_US.csv` for reference.

Comment: sorry mate can't check it right now I'm only using mobile. but I think they are generated because they are as theme strings

Comment: can you check from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Comment: I already checked this, this is for how we can use theme strings in phtml file. I still feel there is way to do some html related changes to translation dictionaries messages whether you made changes in csv or other way

Comment: I don't think so because as per documentation translation are only for the text translation

Comment: the reason anchor tag was used in the translation file because it is generated when i18n tool was run

Comment: That is not completely what I looking for.  I need a way to do html related changes to translation related message because some of the tutorial suggested me to made changes in csv file. if you said it is not possible I can accept your claim because I don't have much research on this one but tell me other way to do html related changes to translation dictionaries messages (as I mentioned in my question). Still for your effort. +1

Comment: okay can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92178/discussion-between-magefms-and-muhammad-hasham).